# Create a for loop that adds data to an object

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I want to create an object by iterating through another one, and essentially appending to that new object.

So the issue at the moment is that the loop finishes with the final value of `desiredData = JSON.parse(row[i]["Results"])` being added to the object `i` times. We should have `i` different objects added.

That is `scoreObjectToSend[desiredUserId]` contains the same object for all `desiredUserId`'s.

I've tried using promises and some other JavaScript methods but to no use.

What I require is a loop over users, that adds their data to an object Object.

```
let raceData = {};
let desiredData = {};
let actualRaceString = raceArray[raceIndex]; // raceIndex defined earlier
let numberOfUsers = row.length; // row defined earlier
let i;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
    let desiredUserId = row[i]["Usernames"];
    let desiredData = JSON.parse(row[i]["Results"]);
    raceData[actualRaceString] = desiredData;
    scoreObjectToSend[desiredUserId] = raceData;
}
```

Comment: Would you, please, edit your post so that it's clear what exactly you have and what you expect to get?

Comment: `let desiredUserId = row[i]["Usernames"];`  Unless you really like using mix matched variables names, that doesn't look correct. :)

Comment: Instead of overwriting the same object and keeping the object reference. Simply construct a new object: `scoreObjectToSend[desiredUserId] = {[actualRaceString]:desiredData};`

Comment: @EsbenAndersen - you da man